# Gerrit replication plugin reload with error "lacks ${name} placeholder in FileBasedConfig"

Tags: ubuntu, gitlab, gerrit

The server which I deploied Gerrit's OS is `Ubuntu 18.04.05`, and my Gitlab server's IP address is `192.168.0.167`. I tried using `replication` plugin to push gerrit project to local Gitlab server. My `gerrit_site/etc/replication.config` file likes below:

```
[remote "test_project"]
    url = git@192.168.0.167:testuser/test_project.git
    push = +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*
    push = +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
    push = +refs/changes/*:refs/changes/*
    threads = 3
    project = test_project
```

And I tried reloading `replication` plugin by below command:

```
ssh -l gerrit_admin -p 29418 127.0.0.1 gerrit plugin reload replication
```

And I got below error:

```
fatal: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) [Guice/ErrorInjectingConstructor]: ConfigInvalidException: remote.test_project.url "git@192.168.0.167:testuser/test_project.git" lacks ${name} placeholder in FileBasedConfig[/home/gerrit/gerrit_site/etc/replication.config]
  at DestinationsCollection.<init>(DestinationsCollection.java:72)
  at DestinationsCollection.class(DestinationsCollection.java:50)
  while locating DestinationsCollection
  while locating ReplicationDestinations

Learn more:
  https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ERROR_INJECTING_CONSTRUCTOR

1 error

======================
Full classname legend:
======================
ConfigInvalidException:  "org.eclipse.jgit.errors.ConfigInvalidException"
DestinationsCollection:  "com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.DestinationsCollection"
ReplicationDestinations: "com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.ReplicationDestinations"
========================
End of classname legend:
========================
```

I wonder if I forgot any configurations? Or have any misunderstanding with
[official document](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/replication/+doc/master/src/main/resources/Documentation/config.md)?
I remember when I install plugin `OAuth`, I need to add a `[plugin "gerrit-oauth"]` section in `gerrit_site/etc/gerrit.config`. But the `replication`'s document has no mention about this. Dose `replication`'s document think I have already done it by default? If so, how should I modify `gerrit_site/etc/gerrit.config`?

Answer (score 0):

I have same issues rencently.
You can check your replication.config, probably replication.config have **duplicate remote name items**, like below, these two items have same name.

Solution: rename the duplicate items to an unique name.

```
[remote "test_project"]
    url = git@192.168.0.167:testuser/test_project.git
    push = +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*
    push = +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
    push = +refs/changes/*:refs/changes/*
    threads = 3
    project = test_project

[remote "test_project"]
    url = git@192.168.0.167:testuser/another.git
    push = +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*
    push = +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
    push = +refs/changes/*:refs/changes/*
    threads = 3
    project = test_project
```